# With VBA, how to import a xlsx file into a xlsm without opening the xlsx file?

Tags: vba, excel

This is part of my current code:

Option Explicit

```
Sub ImportData()

    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook   As Workbook
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant

    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel 2007, *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa", Title:="Select File To Import")
    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    Call ReadDataFromCloseFile(fNameAndPath)


    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = Nothing
    Set wkbSourceBook = Nothing

End Sub

Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile(filePath As Variant)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim src As Workbook

    Set src = Workbooks.Open(filePath, True, True)

' COPY DATA FROM SOURCE (CLOSE WORKGROUP) TO THE DESTINATION WORKBOOK.
' GET THE TOTAL ROWS FROM THE SOURCE WORKBOOK.
Dim lastLine As Long   ' last line from source
lastLine = src.Worksheets(source_sheet_1_name).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("abc").Range("A3:A40")).Value= src.Worksheets("cde").Range("A4:A41").Value


' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
src.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
Set src = Nothing

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

According to [this](http://www.encodedna.com/excel/copy-data-from-closed-excel-workbook-without-opening.htm), the source workbook of the data will not be opened. However, as soon as I clicked the file name in the file browser to select the file to be imported, excel opened the file.

Does anyone know how I should achieve the objective (regardless of the link in the last paragraph)?

(My objective is to copy/import certain columns from an xlsx file to xlsm file according to certain criterien automatically after the user indicate the file to be imported (without opening the file to be imported). However, after I select the file to be imported by double click, the file to be imported is merely opened. The program does not carry forward to import the corresponding columns after the file to be imported is open.)

Comment: The code you linked passed two parameters to.the workbook open event that you haven't included.

Comment: What is your objective?  For example, you could copy the xlsx file to a temporary file, open the temporary file, import its contents, then delete it.  The link you provided has a sample which opens the source workbook in readonly mode.  Which is not the same as not opening it at all, but may meet your requirements.

Comment: @ainwood I tried to include that, it does not work as I wanted either.

Comment: @Joe It says in the link "Excel would not physically open the file"

Comment: @Joe I just edited the question to add my objective.

Comment: The link you mention does say "without Opening it" - however, what the author *means* by that could be better written as "without LOCKING it" - i.e. they're opening it READ-ONLY.

Comment: It's impossible to read a file without *Opening it* if you consider Opening a file as reading it into memory. The nearest thing would be to use a Data connection to extract a range from the file but even then, the file is being 'opened' - just not visible to the user. As @Joe asks, what is your objective here?

Comment: @CLR Thank you. So how to use a data connection as you said?

Comment: @CLR I just updated the last paragraph again . Is my objective is clear now?

Comment: Using either method, Data Connection or hidden Open/Close - both involve the file being 'opened'. One does it natively as part of the import process, the other has to be coded (as it is in your link). As you have a solution - why try something else?

Comment: @CLR What do you mean by "something else"?

Comment: The something else would be using Data Connection. If you really wanted to do that, record a macro where you Get External Data > From Other Sources > From XML data import > Browse to the file > Choose the range. Tell it you want a table and where you want it put and boom, there it is, in a refresh-able table. But as I say, you already have a solution that works in that link. Why not use it?

Comment: What @CLR mentioned is correct, you can really not achieve what you want without opening the file in some way shape or form.  Is there a reason you do not want to open the file?  Aside from attempting a data connection, what's wrong with `screenupdating = false`, open in `read-only`, and set the `.visible = false`?

Comment: @CLR Thank you. I will try this later. The solution in the link will open the new file for the user to see, which I don't want.

Comment: @Busse Thank you. How should I use `.visible = false`? `src.visible= false`?

Comment: @Aqqqq, actually you would do `Application.Visible = False`.  So after you open your src file, you would write that, then the rest of the code you want, then `Application.Visible = True`.  This will actually hide everything until you call it `true` again, so make sure you close out of your src workbook before making it true, otherwise you may see it.  I would also recommend using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`, at the beginning and end. To both speed it up, and make it look more seamless.

Comment: @Busse Thank you. I will try this later.

Comment: @Busse Do you know why the code after the line `Set src = Workbooks.Open(filePath, True, True)` is not carried out?

Comment: @Aqqqq try removing the `Application.Visible` commands, and just keep the `ScreenUpdating` commands.  See if the commands are still carried out. If they are carried out with the Visible commands removed, then it means whatever you are trying to attempt requires the application to be visible.  Unfortunately some code does require the workbook to be visible (from what I understand).

Comment: @Busse Actually the code after the line `Set src = Workbooks.Open(filePath, True, True)` is not carried out even without `Application.Visible`, as I indicated in the last paragraph in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149232/discussion-between-busse-and-aqqqq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do here.  The file needs to be opened, one way or another.  But making it as locked down/hidden as possible will be the key.

You can try a few different things:

1) Before you open the workbook, set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, and then at the end before closing out of the sub, make sure you set it back to `True`.

2) After opening the workbook with `src = workbooks.open...` try setting `Application.Visible = False`.  Once you are finished with the import process, and closing out of the source workbook, make sure you set it back to true: `Application.Visible = True`.

This should allow you to open the workbook, keep the updating off so no one can see what happens, and close out of the workbook with minimal resistance/visibility.

The reason it might be causing an error, or just outright not working is possibly from the workbook sheet name you are trying to call.  I do not see the assignment of the variable, so `lastLine = src.Worksheets(source_sheet_1_name)` should actually say the sheetname in it, such as `lastLine = src.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Give this a shot and let me know.